# what orm to use or just not use it

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, orm

I am starting a relatively small project, one person about three four month of work.
.net 3.5 with MySQL.
And I don't have too much DB work, most of it POP and PUSH of information. Each time against one table only simple queries.
My concern is ORM will introduce unneeded complexity.

Any suggestions? what to use or should I at all.

Comment: Deciding on a .NET ORM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 1):

For what sounds like a small project, use whatever you're most familiar with, unless performance is a huge concern--then probably avoid any ORM. ORMs are most useful for rapid development where performance is not always the highest concern (or where queries are so simple that performance of an ORM is perfect anyway).  So it sounds like an ORM is appropriate for your project... but if you have to learn an ORM just for this project, don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a NoSQL approach (like RavenDB) instead of db and ORM because the only setup that you will need to do is to install the server. With the ORM approach, you will need to set up the database and mappings.

Of course, take the NoSQL approach only if MySQL is not a requirement.

Comment: yep, `Each time against one table only simple queries` seems like a perfect fit to document DB

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are going to **learn ORM** I would suggest to **not use it**. Keep stuff **simple**, unless the reason of this project is just help you study ORM.
2. If you already now some, and considering that the project is small, so no skyrocket performance requirements, **use ORM** definitely.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about complexity I would consider the use of a code generator, to generate your CRUD operations 
mygeneration is a good example of free code generator, that will remove the tedious task of manually creating DAL & stored procedure code.
In my experience it will get you 80% of the way there, and IMHO is ideal for small projects.
(but will take a bit of configuration to get the templates to generate code exactly how you want it to)